# Prevent file from being readed using request method

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

So, i have a code in here that reads a .php file from a folder,

```
#Coded by artemis#1551

import os
from os import system
import requests
import time
from time import sleep

print("server_data.php Reader")
print("Coded by artemis#1551")
ip = input('IP Address > ')
print("Succesfully readed, please wait 5 seconds.....")

post = requests.post(f'http://{ip}/growtopia/server_data.php')
sleep(5)
print('Target server_data.php : ')
print('\n')
print(post.text)
print("\nReaded!")
sleep(10)
```

The main function of this script is read a .php file from a VPS IP.
And i want to make a script that, preventing the .php file from being readed and there will be a logs is someone trying to read it. How to do it?

Comment: I don't understand what "preventing the .php file from being readed (sic) and there will be a logs is someone trying to read it" means. Do you want to create a Python script that will somehow block people from accessing `server_data.php` for any IP you input? Or do you want to modify server configuration to forbid access to that file?

Comment: Yea, similar to blocking the IP